# Why are constant volume and constant pressure heat capacities basically the same for solids? Are degrees of freedom involved?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, degrees-of-freedom

I knowv that $C_V=\frac{\frac{f}{2} Nk_B}{m}$ and $C_P=\frac{(\frac{f}{2} +1)Nk_B}{m}$. Since for solids their values are very close to each other, I would assume $\frac{f}{2} +1$ is very close to $\frac{f}{2}$. Namely, I thought I would need to have $\frac{f}{2} >> 1$. This would require a high number of degrees of freedom. However, is this the case? We are talking about a solid, of which the particles can move in less directions then, let's say, a gas molecule. Or is the very constraint that makes the number of degrees of freedom get very high? And is this the case or is there another explanation for why $C_V$ and $C_P$ have close values for solids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement the qualitative answers, here's the math. [We know that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities) $$C_P-C_V=\frac{VT\alpha^2}{\beta_T},$$ for all materials, where $C$ is the heat capacity (at constant pressure $P$ or volume $V$), $T$ is the temperature, $\alpha$ is the thermal expansion coefficient, and $\beta_T$ is the isothermal compressibility.

Solids typically have much smaller volumes and expansion coefficients than gases, although their compressibilities are also much smaller. The squared $\alpha$ term causes the heat capacities to be very similar.

A problem with oliver's answer is that it refers to the misconception that $C_P>C_V$ because the material must expand and do work against the atmosphere when pressure is held constant. (This misconception is repeated in the accepted answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187794/why-specific-heat-at-constant-pressure-is-greater-than-specific-heat-at-constant), for example.) But the equation above shows that $C_P>C_V$ even when thermal contraction occurs, i.e., when $\alpha<0$, because the term is squared. In fact, the expansion-against-the-atmosphere argument is reliable only for ideal gases (for which $\alpha=1/T$); condensed matter stores energy in internal modes when free to expand or contract, and this contributes to the finding of $C_P>C_V$.

A problem with Chet Miller's answer is that it might imply that $C_P\approx C_V$ because the compressibility $\beta_T$ is small. But $\beta_T$ is in the denominator, so decreasing it alone should make $C_P-C_V$ larger. The resolution is that low-$\beta_T$ materials are also low-$\alpha$ materials; in fact, incompressibility implies zero thermal expansion $\alpha$. As shown above, the squaring of a small $\alpha$ term causes it to dominate the expression and imply $C_P\approx C_V$.

Comment: Interesting fact about thermal contraction. Never thought about that. +1

Answer (score 1):

Although changing the temperature of a solid under *constant volume* conditions can cause extremely high pressures, the corresponding volume changes under *constant pressure* conditions are very small, so the amount of work that a solid can do while expanding when heated, is also very small. It is this work that makes the difference between $C_P$ and $C_V$, which explains why they are not that much different.

To put it colloquially: by heating a metal block, you can probably lift a whole skyscraper by a 1mm, but you aren't able to design a lift by this principle, even if it should only carry a few people from the lobby to the first floor.

Comment: Okay. So degrees of freedom do not factor into this at all?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how degrees of freedom come into play. I have only covered the bird's eye view. Maybe someone else can answer this.

Comment: @Agnese: by the way, are you sure that these formulae are valid also for solids? At first glance, these look a lot like the ones for ideal gases... For the ideal gas, internal energy only depends on temperature, but AFAIK it's more complicated for solids due to interactions between atoms/molecules...

Comment: That's true. I wanted to make a quick comparison with gases, but I have just looked into it and the formulae are different for solids. It seems like the number of degrees of freedom is equal to the number of modes in a solid, which if I am not wrong is related to its lattice structure. So maybe my guess on solids having a high number of degrees of freedom could make sense, assumed the number of modes is high enough?

Comment: I mean, in a very approximate way, since I derived it in a very approximate way.

Answer (score 0):

It is because solids and liquids are very close to being incompressible.  So it doesn't matter whether the pressure is changing or not.