# Why is the value of the heat capacity ratio $\gamma$ never less than 1?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, molecules, adiabatic

For an monoatomic gas, the value of the [heat capacity ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) $\gamma$ is 1.67
For diatomic gases, the value of γ (gamma) is 1.40
For many atomic gases, the value of γ (gamma) is 1.33

It's never less than 1! Why?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187794/why-specific-heat-at-constant-pressure-is-greater-than-specific-heat-at-constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably by $\gamma$ you are referring the to the ratio of the specific heat at constant pressure $c_{p}$ to the specific heat at constant volume $c_V$ as applied to an isentropic process for an ideal gas. For an ideal gas

$$c_{P}=c_{V}+R\tag{1}$$

Thus for an ideal gas, $c_P$ is always greater than $c_V$ by an amount equal to the universal gas constant.

Equation (1) can be derived from the basic definitions of the specific heats and enthalpy, combined with the ideal gas law, as follows:

Specific heat definitions:

For constant pressure:

$$c_p = \frac{dh}{dT}$$

For constant temperature:

$$c_v = \frac{du}{dT}$$

Definition of specific enthalpy (h)

$$h = u + Pv$$

From the ideal gas law

$$Pv=RT$$

Therefore

$$h = u+RT$$

Taking the derivative of the last equation with respect to temperature:

$$\frac {dh}{dT} =\frac {du}{dT}+R$$

Substituting the specific heat definitions into the last equation, we get

$$c_p – c_v = R$$

For data on various gases see:https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-ratio-d_608.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

During constant volume heating, the gas's volume is fixed, and hence it does no work on its surroundings. During constant *pressure* heating, the gas is allowed to expand against its surroundings, thereby doing work on the surroundings and hence losing some of the energy that it is gaining from heating. As a consequence, the specific heat at constant pressure *has* to be larger than the specific heat at constant volume, and so $\gamma>1$.

Comment: Note that this argument works for any system that expands when heated, not just for a gas.

Comment: [Here's why it doesn't apply to a system that contracts with heating.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities)

Comment: However, this argument becomes less obvious for fluids with a negative thermal expansion coefficient. Still, the same inequality holds.

Answer (score 4):

A simple argument would be that the heat capacity ratio for an ideal gas is related to the [degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(physics_and_chemistry)), $f$, via,
$$\gamma=1+\frac{2}{f}\equiv\frac{f+2}{f}$$
Since the degree of freedom specifies the number of ways a molecule/gas can move (translational, rotational, vibrational) in a given $d$-dimensional space, then it must be strictly positive ($f>0)$, which means that the adiabatic index will satisfy $\gamma>1$ for all $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Constant pressure heat capacity is always greater or equal to the constant volume heat capacity for perfect and real gases and for liquids, i.e., for every simple system described by $N$, $V$, $T$ variables.

The reason is a general purely thermodynamic relation between $C_p$ and $C_V$:
$$
C_P = C_V + \frac{TV\alpha^2}{\chi_T} \tag{1}
$$
where $\alpha$ is the thermal expansion coefficient, and $\chi_T$ is the isothermal compressibility. The identity can be easily derived, and details can be found in every good thermodynamics textbook. Equation $(1)$ implies
$$
C_P \geq C_V  ~~~~~~~ \Rightarrow  ~~~~~~~~~ \gamma=\frac{C_P}{C_V} \geq 1
$$
i.e., $\gamma$ can never be smaller than one.

Notice that there is only one case where the equality to one may hold for finite values of the heat capacities: the rare but not impossible case of zero thermal expansion materials (see, for instance, [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.chemmater.1c01007)).

Answer (score 3):

$$\gamma=\frac{C_p}{C_v}=\frac{C_v+R}{C_v}=1+\frac{R}{C_v}$$We know that R is a positive constant and the heat capacity at constant volume is greater than zero (a gas internal energy increases with increasing temperature).  So $\gamma>1$.